# Problem loading SID to geoserver

Tags: geoserver, raster, mrsid

I have a folder with .sdw and .sid files I want to server using geoserver.
I've followed the instructions [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#data-gdal) which basically means to install GDAL extensions and binaries on the geoserver machine.

When I go back to stores after reseting the service I still don't see MrSID store.
any thoughts? running on windows server 2008.

Here are the steps I did to install it on server 2008 x64 on geoserver 2.4.0:

1. Downloaded GDAL extention from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer%20Extensions/2.4.0/geoserver-2.4.0-gdal-plugin.zip) and put it in Geoserver/web-inf/lib
2. Downloaded Imageio-Ext jars from [here](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/) and put them in Geoserver/web-inf/lib
3. Downloaded gdal-data.zip from [here](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/gdal-data.zip) and put it in program files\gdal-data
4. Added GDAL_DATA with path to the folder in no. 3 in system variables
5. Downloaded [gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2008-x64.zip](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2008/gdal-1.9.2-MSVC2008-x64.zip) and put the content in program files\gdal-1.9.2
6. Added no.5 folder to system variable PATH
7. Installed [gdal-19-1500-x64-mrsid.msi](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.7/native/gdal/windows/MSVC2008/gdal-19-1500-x64-mrsid.msi) and put the dll in PATH location (system32)
8. checked that gdalinfo.exe --format MrSid works (and it did)
9. Since I run geoserver as service , I moved the DLLs from 5 (native) to the wrapper\lib folder.
10. Restarted Geoserver service ... Don't see MrSID or any change in stores.

What did I miss ?

There is a section saying :

> Adding support for ECW and MrSID on Windows
>   If you are on Windows and you want to add support for ECW and MrSID there is an extra step to perform.
>   In the Windows packaging ECW and MrSID are built as plugins hence they are not loaded by default but we need to place their DLLs in a location that is pointed by the GDAL_DRIVER_PATH environmental variable. GDAL uses internally this env variable to look up additional drivers (notice that there are a few default places where GDAL will look anyway). For additional information, please, check this link.

Did I miss it ? If so , what needs to be done here ? which files I need to put where ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? The response is marked as solved, but I see no so solution. I am in the exact same situation only I'm on geoserver 2.9. When I start tomcat I get an error in the output window saying that it can't load the mrsid dll because of an unkown procedure; same for ecw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the environment variable GDAL_DRIVER_PATH? Not having that has tripped me up.
Mine looks like C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins. When I ran the GDAL MrSID Extension setup that is where those files ended up.

Comment: Yes I did.
the gdalinfo.exe --formats runs.. but I dont see new stores in geoserver

Comment: I do not have any other suggestions. I know it works on windows server 2008, and I had to read the setup instructions very carefully a couple of times to get the Mr Sid store.

Comment: I'll edit the post with all steps I did , Will be nice if you could follow and say If I missed something.

Comment: I've edited my question , I'll be more than happy if you could check my steps.

Comment: Which MSVC GDAL did you download ? 2005 , 2008 , 2010 ?